# How does not compile angular/cli project if there are errors based on eslint?

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular-cli, tslint

How to change webpack.config.js file inside angular/cli project that `ng serve command will not ignore tslint rules.

Answer (score 0):

To use ESLint, include these dependencies in your package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
        "eslint": "^4.1.1",
        "eslint-loader": "^1.8.0"
    }
```

To execute ESlint before the execution of other modules, include the following in your webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
   rules: [
           {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "eslint-loader"
           },
   ...
   ]
}
```

The important aspect hereby is `enforce: "pre"`.

To configure ESLint, create a file called .eslintrc.js and specify your rule set.

For more information and a working setup (webpack, ESLint,...), have a look at my [Webpack starter project](http://www.matthiassommer.it/software-architecture/webpack-template-classic-website-setup/). It is also [available at Github](https://github.com/matthiassommer/webpack-classic-website-template).

Comment: I asked about tslint rules.

Comment: You wrote eslint in your thread caption. It would be also better if you provide code.